# Spring service locator without autowiring it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, service-locator

Having this code:

```
public class ClassA {

    private InterfaceB interfaceB;

    private int a

    private int b;

    public ClassA(int a, int b) {
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
    }
}
```

There could be several objects of `ClassA` in my application, created on demand at runtime. But all of them should use the same concrete implementation of `InterfaceB` class (there are several implementations of `InterfaceB` but only one is used at runtime depending on the platform used). And there should be only one`InterfaceB` object in the application (singleton class).

I can not autowired `interfaceB` as `ClassA` objects are created at runtime when `a` and `b` constructor parameters are known.

How could I use Spring Framework to implement the service locator pattern here? My plan is to instantiate the service locator in `ClassA` and use it to get the `InterfaceB` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an additional class that will be creating your `ClassA` and it will be holding a reference to an `interfaceB`. For example:

```
@Component
public class ClassAFactory {

    @Autowired
    private InterfaceB interfaceB;

    public ClassA create(int a, int b) {
       return new ClassA(a, b, interfaceB);
    }
}
```

In this case you have to extend the `ClassA` to pass an `interfaceB`.
Then somewhere in your code you could:

```
@Autowired
private ClassAFactory factory ;

...

ClassA classA = factory.create(1,1);
```

Comment: How I would get the factory when not autowired by Spring? I mean, the objects holding the reference to the factory are not beans itself.

Comment: So you want to create `ClassA`  outside the code managed by spring? Can you give an example how do you want to create `ClassA`?

Comment: You can assume that a serviceX holds a in memory List of ClassX objects and perform CRUD for them. ClassX objects have one attribute that is a ClassA object. In a given time (for example some user requested that) the service is requested to add a new ClassX object. How would the ClassX object get the factory? The 'new' for the ClassX objects are performed by the ServiceX

Comment: Factory should be in serviceX (for example with @Autowired). If you want to change ClassX by adding ClassA then serviceX should do something like this: `classX.classA = factory.create(1,1);`

Comment: If factory is in serviceX in order to inject ClassA objects to ClassB it couples the serviceX with the factory and with ClassA and expose needlessly the internal details of ClassX (violating information hiding principle).  I think the factory should be in ClassA, and in the constructor of ClassA it gets the InterfaceB objects using the Factory. If i declares the Factory as a Bean with the @Component, how I get it using Spring??

Comment: Factory with `@Component` will be accessible in spring for example via `@Autowired`. Can you give an example of code that shows how objects of classA, classB and classX are using. It will be helpful in explaining.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a service locator pattern, in the modern spring driven applications it usually not required anymore.

I'll try to address all your statements from the Spring Framework's integration standpoint:

> There could be several objects of ClassA in my application, created on demand at runtime.

Spring is a runtime framework, so everything is created in runtime anyway. If you need many objects created by demand you can declare ClassA as a spring bean with scope prototype.
Other beans could have this prototype bean injected. Another possible approach if you know which instances will be created during the application startup is to define many beans of the same type and use spring's qualifier feature to differentiate between them during the injection.

> But all of them should use the same concrete implementation of InterfaceB class (there are several implementations of InterfaceB but only one is used at runtime depending on the platform used).

This means that `InterfaceB` can be a regular singleton, however, given different implementations you can define something like this:

```
@Configuration 
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name="myprop", havingValue="true")
    public InterfaceB interfaceBImpl1() {
        return new InterfaceBImpl1();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name="myprop", havingValue="false")
    public InterfaceB interfaceBImpl2() {
        return new InterfaceBImpl2();
    }
}
```

> I can not autowired interfaceB as ClassA objects are created at runtime when a and b constructor parameters are known.

Actually you can, no issues with that. Define the bean of classA as a prototype.

Check also `@Lazy` annotation of spring in case you want to initialize the instance of that classA upon the first invocation only.

```
public class ClassA {
  /// fields ///

  public ClassA(InterfaceB intefaceB, int a, int b) {
    this.intefaceB = intefaceB;
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
}
@Configuration 
class MyConfig {

   @Bean
   @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
   public ClassA classA(InterfaceB bImpl, int a, int b) {
      return new ClassA(bImpl, int a, int b);
   }
}
```

**Update 1**

Based on OP's comments:

Here is the working example:

Add the following dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

It contains only interfaces and has not transitive dependencies

Then based on your use case explained in comment:

```
public class InterfaceB {
}

public class ClassA {
    private final InterfaceB interfaceB;

    public ClassA(InterfaceB interfaceB) {
        this.interfaceB = interfaceB;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Doing something on instance: [ " + this + " ]. The interface B instance is [ "+ interfaceB + " ]");
    }
}


public class ServiceA {

    private final List<ClassA> classAList;
    private Provider<ClassA> classAProvider;

    public ServiceA(Provider<ClassA> classAProvider) {
        this.classAProvider = classAProvider;
        this.classAList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addNewObject() {
        ClassA newObj = classAProvider.get();
        classAList.add(newObj);
    }

    public void doWithAllElementsInList() {
        classAList.forEach(ClassA::doSomething);
    }
}
```

Spring configuration looks like this:

```
public class SingletonWithPrototypesConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServiceA serviceA(Provider<ClassA> classAProvider) {
        return new ServiceA(classAProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public ClassA classA(InterfaceB interfaceB) {
        return new ClassA(interfaceB);
    }

    @Bean
    public InterfaceB interfaceB() {
        return new InterfaceB();
    }
}
```

And the main class that gets the service A from the application context (in your case it should be probably a controller or any other business flow):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SingletonWithPrototypesConfig.class);
        ServiceA serviceA = ctx.getBean(ServiceA.class);
        serviceA.doWithAllElementsInList(); // won't print anything, 0 elements in the list
        System.out.println("---------");
        serviceA.addNewObject();
        serviceA.addNewObject();
        serviceA.doWithAllElementsInList();
    }
```

In the last print note that ClassA instances are different, the interfaceB is the same shared instance though.

Sidenote: the Provider is something integrated with spring already, it resides in `javax.inject.Provider` of that new jar.

Comment: How I create InterfaceB objects and  ClassA objects on demand using this example? Doing something like AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = 
            new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class) then  context.getBean("classA") ??

Comment: Please update the question with a code snippet of the object that actually uses "classA", so that I could show how to do it in your case. Basically you should never use application context directly in your business code...

Comment: You can assume that a serviceX holds a in memory List of ClassX objects and perform CRUD for them. ClassX objects have one attribute that is a ClassA object. In a given time (for example some user requested that) the service is requested to add a new ClassX object. How would the ClassX object get the factory? The 'new' for the ClassX objects are performed by the ServiceX

Comment: @MABC - please check out the update on my answer, I've run this example on my machine and it reproduces your case and solves the issue. Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Why simply dont  this.interfaceB = ctx.getBean("InterfaceB)" in ClassA constructor?

Comment: This will also work, but this way you make your business code dependent on the application context (spring) at the level of code - this means basically two things: testing is more complicated and you can't reuse the code without spring. Its a question of design and coupling I would say